# How do I solve a recurring authentication error?

Tags: authentication, opensuse

I'm running openSuSE 12.2, a fairly standard install, didn't do anything crazy with it.  It pops up a red "Failed to gain Authentication" box in the lower right of the screen every 5-10 minutes or so.  It then fades away rapidly.  It's really annoying and I have no idea why it's doing that.  Anyone else already solve this problem and have a solution to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that openSuSE 12.3 came out.  I did the upgrade.  Have not seen this error ever since.